# Set Option Value Based on Multiple Variables

Tags: php, logic

Here is the scoop.  I am making a product calculator which has 5 different options, but the value I need to apply to the initial variable is dependent on two separate variables to determine the correct value to multiply by.

So logically, I have value A which I need to multiply by variable B, however, the value of B is dependent on the input from variables C and D.  Value B is an absolute value.  To add insult to injury, if value A is less than 12, I need to subtract .5 or .25 depending on the value of variable C from the original value before B is applied.  I am lost here.

Here is the original equation from the excel spreadsheet that was given to me to adapt:

=IF(AND(B9="Option_1",B11="Horizontal"),D6+K6+1-0.00515464*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_1",B11="Vertical"),D6+K6+1-0.0064433*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_2",B11="Horizontal",D6>12),D6+K6-0.5+1-0.010417*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_2",B11="Vertical",D6>12),D6+K6-0.25+1-0.005208*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_2",B11="Horizontal",D6<12),D6+K6-0.25+1-0.010417*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_2",B11="Vertical",D6<12),D6+K6+1-0.005208*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_3",B11="Vertical",D6>12),D6+K6-0.5+1-0.010417*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_3",B11="Horizontal",D6>12),D6+K6-0.25+1-0.005208*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_3",B11="Vertical",D6<12),D6+K6-0.25+1-0.010417*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_3",B11="Horizontal",D6<12),D6+K6+1-0.005208*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_4",B11="Vertical"),D6+K6+1-0.03125*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_4",B11="Horizontal"),D6+K6+1-0.02083*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_5",B11="Vertical"),D6+K6+1-0.0625*(D6+K6),IF(AND(B9="Option_5",B11="Horizontal"),D6+K6+1-0.052083*(D6+K6)))))))))))))))

Thanks!

Comment: Is this even PHP? I've never seen something like that. `) {{if (>12) {` that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Probably not. I am trying to adapt this equation from an excel spreadsheet and I thought I could nest if functions to eliminate the "and" or "or" functions from the excel formula.  I am confused.

Comment: I think it's best if you show your original Excel cell value with the calculation in it.

Comment: Alright, I replaced my illogical PHP with the original equation.  I'm not sure this makes it any easier to understand, but maybe. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh god, please kill me. Don't ever use such spaghetti equations. Write down the logic on paper, then start to express it step by step in code. And not as this nested Cthulu code, but logically, step by step: `if (...) $a = ...; if (...) $a = ...; if (...) $b = ...; $c = $b + $a; ...`

Comment: Jesus, I can't do anything to make you people happy.  I was asked to provide the original equation.  Look, I'm here for help, if I could do it myself I would spare myself the indignity; trust me.  That is a helpful suggestion, however, so I thank you.  Is that the correct syntax?  I am struggling because there are three inputs which total 20 possible equations. A will always be A, but B is dependent on C and D.  I really need to know how to define B.

Comment: Let's put it this way: we're here to provide help, but we're not hand-holding and writing custom code just for you. Pay a consultant if you need that. We're happy to provide solutions to general problems which will help other visitors in the future as well. What you need is simply to deconstruct some complex business logic and rewrite it in a sane, simple way. That won't help anyone in the future, yet will cost anyone trying to wrap his head around your code a lot of spare time.

Comment: And yes, that's pretty much the syntax you're looking for. One operation per line. Declare `$a`. Declare `$b`. Check some condition, change `$b` if necessary. Check some condition, change `$b` if necessary. ... Add `$a` and `$b`...

Comment: That's fair. I apologize. What if I simplify the question. Can I use PHP to define an option value dynamically based on the input of my other 2 variables?  <option value="<?php ... ?>"> Option_1 </option>  At the crux of the matter, that's really all I need to know.

Comment: Well, the answer to that is *yes*. You can define any value for an HTML element you want. It's all just program output. And that can be anything. And that can depend on whatever you want. You just need to write the code.

Comment: I will try to become a better StackOverflow user.  I'm a designer, but my company assumes that "anyone who can internet can do all of the internet."  So I get these projects that are over my head and they refuse to hire consultants or developers.

Comment: If you need to learn PHP (specific to your task), start here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question should probably provide some sort of guidance on how to get from the sort of code that you've provided (a very long string of spreadsheet ternary `IF` functions that is quite hard to understand) to something in PHP that is more concise, and perhaps slightly more readable.

I don't know if I'm good enough at explaining this sort of thing to actually truly help you, but I think the most important steps to take in the process would be to;

**Reformat the code**

Putting each condition on a line of it's own, and each resulting output block on a line of it's own, can be hugely helpful to understanding the logic you've got. This often means that you can see patterns as you look down through the code.

**Group common logic**

Once the code is formatted nicely, and you can perhaps see some patterns emerging, you should be able to group statements into fewer blocks.

---

Having taken these steps myself on the code you provided, this function should provide the same output for the given values of `D6`, `K6`, `B9` and `B11` as you were getting in the spreadsheet;

```
function calculateValue($D6, $K6, $B9, $B11) {
    $modifiers = array(
        'Option_1' => array('Horizontal' => 0.00515464, 'Vertical' => 0.0064433),
        'Option_2' => array('Horizontal' => 0.010417, 'Vertical' => 0.005208),
        'Option_3' => array('Horizontal' => 0.005208, 'Vertical' => 0.010417),
        'Option_4' => array('Horizontal' => 0.02083, 'Vertical' => 0.03125),
        'Option_5' => array('Horizontal' => 0.052083, 'Vertical' => 0.0625),
    );
    $x = $D6 + $K6;
    $y = $modifiers[$B9][$B11];
    $sub = 0;
    if ($B9 == "Option_2") {
        if ($B11 == "Horizontal") {
            $sub += 0.25;
        }
        if ($D6 > 12) {
            $sub += 0.25;
        }
    } else if ($B9 == "Option_3") {
        if ($B11 == "Vertical") {
            $sub += 0.25;
        }
        if ($D6 > 12) {
            $sub += 0.25;
        }
    }
    return $x - $sub + 1 - $y * $x;
}
```

Hopefully this makes the logic seem more readable and understandable as well.